# Sum of weights of an irreducible representation of $U(N)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, characters, weyl-group, weights

Let $R$ be a finite-dimensional irreducible representation of $U(N)$, with the set of weights $W_R$. Each element of $W_R$ is a vector of length $N$ with integer entries.

Firstly, I would like to know if it is true that $$\sum_{\mu\in W_R}m_\mu\mu=A(R)(1,\ldots,1),$$ where $m_\mu$ is the multiplicity of the weight $\mu$ and $A(R)$ is some integer that varies with the representation. Note that we are considering $U(N)$ rather $SU(N)$, because I think the sum of weights of an irrep vanishes for $SU(N)$.

Secondly, I would like to know if there is a simple formula for $A(R)$, or if there is an existing name for it?

Comment: You are just taking a bare sum of weights, without any multiplicity (according to the dimension of the weight space)?

Comment: @LSpice Sorry I meant to include multiplicities; the question has been edited.

Comment: Since $m_\mu$ is constant on Weyl orbits (because we're dealing with a representation of $G$), $\sum m_\mu\mu$ is Weyl-fixed.  The Weyl-fixed sublattice of the character lattice of $\operatorname{SU}(N)$ is trivial, which is why you always get $0$ there; and is spanned by the character $\operatorname{det} = (1, \dotsc, 1)$ you indicate for $\operatorname U(N)$, so, indeed, you always get your desired equality.  Possibly $A(R)$ can be computed in terms of the highest weight by the Kostant multiplicity formula.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the reply! Do you know a simple proof (or reference) for why the weyl-fixed character lattice of $SU(N)$ is trivial?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439350/sum-of-weights-of-an-irreducible-representation-of-un#comment1133250_439350), it's a straightforward computation: the character lattice-with-$W$-action is naturally identified with the subspace of $\mathbb Z^n$-with-$\mathfrak S_n$ action on which the sum of coördinates is $0$.  The $\mathfrak S_n$-fixed lattice in $\mathbb Z^n$ is spanned by $(1, \dotsc, 1)$, and only the trivial vector in that span has the sum of its coördinates $0$.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks! now it's obvious...

Comment: Hmm, I wonder whether $A(R)$ is the integer $N$ such that $\det \circ R = \det(\cdot)^N$ ….

Comment: @LSpice If we sum over the components of the formula, we get $N A(R)=\sum_{\mu\in W_R}m_\mu\sum_{i=1}^N\mu_i$, but now $\sum_i\mu_i=\sum_i\lambda_i$ where $\lambda$ is the highest weight, because all weights differ from each other by a linear combination of roots $\alpha$, and $\sum_i\alpha_i=0$. Therefore $\sum_{\mu\in W_R}m_\mu\sum_{i}\mu_i=(\sum_i\lambda_i)\sum_{\mu\in W_R}m_\mu=\text{dim}(R)\sum_i\lambda_i$, and we get $A(R)=\frac{\text{dim}(R)}{N}\sum_i\lambda_i$. I'm not sure if this formula can be further simplified. One could use the Weyl dimension formula to compute $\text{dim}(R)$.

Comment: I thought I used an idea from your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439350/sum-of-weights-of-an-irreducible-representation-of-un#comment1133302_439350) to make my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/439408) more explicit, but now I realise that I just wasn't understanding your comment properly, and what I added to my answer is exactly what you said.  Sorry about that!

Comment: [Correction](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1133252):  the character lattice of $\operatorname{SU}(N)$ is more naturally identified with the *quotient* of $\mathbb Z^N$ by $\mathbb Z(1, \dotsc, 1)$.  (What I wrote is naturally identified with the *co*character lattice.)  Nonetheless, one still computes that $(\mathbb Z^N/\mathbb Z(1, \dotsc, 1))^{\mathfrak S_N}$ is trivial.  (I also, [there](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1133252) and [elsewhere](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1133257), switched $N$s and $n$s.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439350/sum-of-weights-of-an-irreducible-representation-of-un#comment1133244_439350), your sum is a Weyl-fixed character, so trivial for $G = \operatorname{SU}(N)$ and a multiple of $\det = (1, \dotsc, 1)$ for $\operatorname U(N)$.

To be concrete, as I guessed in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439350/sum-of-weights-of-an-irreducible-representation-of-un#comment1133257_439350), one sees that your sum $\sum_\mu m_\mu\mu$ (the sum taking place in the character lattice $X^*(T)$ of the (implicitly chosen) maximal torus $T$, not in $\mathbb C[X^*(T)]$ as in the Weyl character formula) is precisely the character of $\det \circ R$.  Again, since $\det \circ R$ is Weyl invariant and $\det$ spans the Weyl-invariant part of the character lattice, your integer $A(R)$ is precisely the integer $n$ such that we have $\det \circ R = \det(\cdot)^n$.

Inspired by [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439350/sum-of-weights-of-an-irreducible-representation-of-un#comment1133302_439350), I realise we can be a little more explicit.  (On having written this, I realise that it was actually *exactly* what you were saying; I mistook your $\lambda_i$ for an indexing of weights, rather than a component of $\lambda$.  Oops, sorry!)

Let $\lambda$ be the highest weight of $R$.  Then all weights $\mu$ of $R$ agree on the centre of $\operatorname U(N)$ with $\lambda$.  Specifically, they all act as $z I_N \mapsto z^\ell$ for some integer $\ell$.  (If we think of $\lambda$ as an element of $\mathbb Z^N$, then $\ell$ is the sum of the components.)  Thus, we have that $R$ agrees on the centre with $z I_N \mapsto z^\ell I_{\dim(R)}$, so $\det \circ R$ agrees on the centre with $z I_N \mapsto \det(z^\ell I_{\dim(R)}) = z^{\ell\dim(R)} = \det(z I_N)^{\ell\dim(R)/N}$, so $A(R)$ equals $\ell\dim(R)/N$.  As you [point out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439350/sum-of-weights-of-an-irreducible-representation-of-un#comment1133302_439350), we can use the [Weyl dimension formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl_dimension_formula) to compute $\dim(R)$ in terms of $\lambda$ if desired.